# CSS - component transparency

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create icons for different severities and managed to get that right, but now I'm struggling to use the nth-child (odd/even) as the outline of the border-radius doesn't seem to change color. I've tried border color to different colours and even set it to transparent but nothing seems to work.

if you increase the size of the web page and you look on row 2 and 4 you see 'artefacts' around the 'button icons'. I'm trying to get rid of this.

Sample code is located at:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/infy101/dgjkLz51/)

First 2 rows of code:

```
<table class="standard">
  <tr>
    <td width="500">Customer 1</td>
    <td align="right">
      <table>
        <tr class="standard">
          <td>
            <div class="decommissioned">
              <p>2</p>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="inactive">
              <p>2</p>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="delivery">
              <p>5</p>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="live_under_review">
              <p>1</p>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="live_approved">
              <p>55</p>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="total">
              <p>65</p>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td width="500">Customer 2</td>
    <td align="right">
      <table>
        <tr class="standard">
          <td>
            <div class="decommissioned">
              <p>2</p>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="inactive">
              <p>2</p>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="delivery">
              <p>5</p>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="live_under_review">
              <p>1</p>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="live_approved">
              <p>55</p>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="total">
              <p>65</p>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

and CSS:

```
.standard {
  height: 20px;
  font: 12px Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px 4px 0px 4px;
}

.standard tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #fff;
}

.standard tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #eee;
}

.live_approved {
  float: left;
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  background: #117711;
  height: 18px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.live_approved p {
  display: table-cell;
  font: 12px Arial;
  color: #fff;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 8px 0px 8px;
}
```

There seems to be an issue on the outsides of the tabular div items as well as between the two cells in each row.

I'm pretty new to css/html so would appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks,

Infy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are applying `background color` to your `tr` elements which are even.

```
.standard tr:nth-child(even) {
background: #eee;
}

.standard tr:nth-child(odd) {
background: #fff;
}
```

Your odd elements are having `background color` white but the even with light grey which looks like a border.

You should target your `tr` separately. You are using nested `table` and `.standard tr` class will target all their child.

TIP: Try to use dev tools of browsers.

Comment: Thanks, sorted now! Much appreciated.